# Rewriting subdomain.domain.com when other 'subdomains' exist

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, httpd, httpd.conf

My httpd.conf looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost 12.34.56.78:80

<VirtualHost 12.34.56.78:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site
ServerName www.example.com

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    ...
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 12.34.56.78:80>
ServerName blog.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog
</VirtualHost>

Listen *:2194

<VirtualHost *:2194>
   Redirect / http://mgr.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to be able to enable 'categories' as subdomains, ie if a user accesses:

```
science.example.com
```

It should show him that URL itself, but show him the contents of www.example.com/science.php

It does not have to be a generic / wildcard based approach - these categories will be a small number that I can specify individually. I just dont want whatever I add to interfere with the existing functioning of the site.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

`ServerAlias *.example.com`

to the vhost and employ these rewrite rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

If you already have a subdomain, eg. `subsub.example.com`, explicitly set as ServerName/ServerAlias for another vhost, it will take precedence over the wildxard vhosts

Comment: Hi. If I want specifically for it to react on science.example.com - how do I do that?

Comment: Add `ServerAlias science.example.com` instead, and change the first Rewrite Condition to: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(science)\. [NC]`. This way you're saying "If the hostname starts with  `science` then:" instead of the first example where the condition is true everytime the hostname "does NOT start with `www` "

Comment: If you don't want anyone to access your site (and get redirected), from other hostnames than the www and the few subdomains you specify, I would probably go with the "wildcard" rewrite rules, where you rewrite all requests that does NOT start with "www", and then ONLY add the subdomains needed as ServerAlias's

Comment: Hmm - thanks for responding... I'm trying the original and OpenDNS is redirecting me to its own page. The domain is registered at one place and the hosting is at the other. Do I need to add any DNS entries?

Comment: Yeah, create a CNAME record for each subdomain and point them to the www. subdomain

Comment: Hi - can you have a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/344984/unable-to-get-mod-rewrite-to-stop-processing as well?